# Cassandra ya no reconoce el comando creativo de Keyspace

Tags: cassandra

Intento crear un keyspace sobre Cassandra con la ayuda del tutorial de tuttorialspoint pero hay un problema :Cuando hago el comando para crear un Keyspace:

```
;CREATE KEYSPACE k1 WITH
    strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy'
    AND trategy_otpions:replication_factor = '1';
    ...
```

O

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE k1 WITH
   ... replication = {'class': 'strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy'
   ... AND trategy_otpions:replication_factor = '1';
   ...
```

Cuando toco la entrada no da nada, solo el '...'

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que existe un error de sintaxis. Puede ver que tiene una comilla antes de strategy_class que no tiene contraparte.

La sentencia correcta seria:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE k1
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
   'replication_factor' : 1 
  };
```

Para mas ejemplos concretos puede referirse a la documentación oficial [aqui](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateKeyspace.html).